# How to sum the value of two array members in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, sum

I am trying to calculate the offset of a label for each shape on a canvas drawing using the `x` value of the shape plus its width, `w`.

I just want to get the sum of the `x` and `w` values and use it as a parameter, like so, of `ctx.fillText()`.

This would then offset the text label so that it is to the right of each shape element.

```
ctx.fillText(data[i].name, +data[i].x + data[i].w, +data[i].y + 15)
```

I have an array:

```
var data = [
    {"name": "Free-OH", "x": "270", "y": "20", "w": "20", "h": "20", "color": "blue"},
    {"name": "Bonded OH", "x": "280", "y": "50", "w": "58", "h": "20", "color": "green"},
    {"name": "-C=-CH", "x": "310", "y": "80", "w": "20", "h": "20", "color": "purple"}  
];
```

with various values that I am using in a JavaScript for loop. Everything works fine until I try to calculate an offset for the label using the value of `data[i].x + data[i].w`.

This doesn't seem to work, nor does creating a variable like

`var offset = data[i].x + data[i].w`

at the beginning of the for loop. Seems like this should be trivially easy, but apparently not. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NjABq/3/). My complete code is below. Thanks very much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Wavelength to Compound</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/
jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("FirstCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeRect(5, 5, 2990, 240);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#DDDDDD";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(5, 210);
ctx.lineTo(2995, 210);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.font = "14pt Arial";
ctx.fillText("0", 10, 235); 
ctx.fillText("30", 2970, 235);


var data = [{"name": "Free-OH", "x": "270", "y": "20", "w": "20", "h": "20", "color": "blue"},
            {"name": "Bonded OH", "x": "280", "y": "50", "w": "58", "h": "20", "color": "green"},
            {"name": "-C=-CH", "x": "310", "y": "80", "w": "20", "h": "20", "color": "purple"}  
];

for (var i = 1; i < 150; i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i*20, 210);
    ctx.lineTo(i*20, 5);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++){
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.fillText(i/2, i*100-7.5, 235);
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
ctx.fillStyle = data[i].color;
ctx.fillRect(data[i].x, data[i].y, data[i].w, data[i].h);
ctx.fillText(data[i].name, +data[i].x + data[i].w, +data[i].y + 15);
}


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="FirstCanvas" width="3000" height="250">
<p>Wavelength to Compound</p>
<div id="content"><div/>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to sum two strings...first change the string to an integer using typesetting

```
var offset = Number(data[i].x) + Number(data[i].w)
```

Comment: `parseInt` needs a radix.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thanks, Pastor Bones, works perfectly now! I forgot the value in the JSON array would come across as a string, since I was working with integers in the other for loops. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`data[i].x` and `data[i].w` are strings. To add them together do one of the following:

```
+data[i].x + +data[i].w;

parseInt(data[i].x, 10) + parseInt(data[i].w, 10);

Number(data[i].x) + Number(data[i].w);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/FDb85/)